# How to prove this integral equality which contains the nonlocal operator, $(-\partial_{xx})^{1/2}$?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Suppose that $\theta(t,x)$ is even about $x$ and is smooth. $0\le \gamma<1/2$, $0<\delta<1-2\gamma$. $\Lambda=(-\partial_{xx})^{1/2}$

**My Question:** How to prove that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta}}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\theta(t,x)-\theta(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta+\gamma}}dx
$$
**My efforts:**
Since $\theta$ is even, $\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta$ is even. Using parseval's theorem, we can obtain
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{x^{1+\delta}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}\theta)(t,0)}{|x|^{1+\delta}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}( \theta(t,x)-\theta(t,0))\Lambda^{\gamma}(|x|^{-(1+\delta)})dx
$$
However, $\Lambda^{\gamma}(|x|^{-(1+\delta)})$ have nonsense.

This question is from the last proof of this paper. Thanks for any help!
[Blow-up of solutions for a 1D transport equation with nonlocal velocity and supercritical dissipation](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272585/1-s2.0-S0001870808X00040/1-s2.0-S0001870807003076/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIBxITU7zdzlOx6HXWtys7A%2BPs5lqnXW%2FRziEL5CvuusYAiB7UlHsaQDX%2F9MsxEyGPcNUF%2Fh%2FRo5%2FIgsUcxsfaijBCCqDBAi9%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAQaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMmmZ7CCd3zpnxCmifKtcD7iKzznthikH9JUevrXWtgGF7qK4wQca4FS0nYPvzpjXhJPtNDceuLP8STMZriv7udhKuw5fhJ1o6U3Jfr73M41y48XzLNHGaAzJ8OeE3XJ7u0zYQvxfCnuwfPTzz8%2FkGApDoCC%2FKGSSjq%2BmrUmAZdfA6DxDFSEptFI%2FAm%2F%2Fm8mgALtakR%2BlP5JLceH3x3Ug9xmQtz21dzXeNXIy%2FHDpHvPKiZPoJl%2Bqgy1PFFVXrIEW907LRHolCfNOiOm3OzYkKweMz3qleXrxpLCckoardNu90PqUiAwm4%2BeKceNML1CGlrx%2FkanQRQIZeh%2BAyK3en5zu7o05Xb1aZ3zJpCy1V48ARuKsVr0Vnm%2BbtuWoHiQZ0YWiDXxnKa1IhUUycquofo7l0dsHP0pfBRTm5HpCgIWRuVG06HMMYNa77%2Bu0oZKs9jSi5m%2FhAoo4nqz5OXPdtBTSdisBh3nYNenlN07xPsQKmsYiztKGrS8JHWcmYhRVTeP1%2Baa9Gf1VN1mzW%2B1IoS6fLfADjmBbjvbQFPKgY6yNXHQK1CUxE27KxfOQMmexLW7L80LVcmD2S0n5fzGe%2FubjFLCK8L3cXUDmskJPdPM2F886qlH6PCvkAHLJqOnE%2BIel5ydB3MNO3q4cGOqYBZQjnGZR6qdA8n%2Bl29mW4xfnazLassGSq1lh%2FbMvuC2NXyspNSUt8Y8M8OrN%2F1mbsaVMV8EcTJ9lKeQ0gFsW86ZnzgfvB2%2FN4tnRv4s76uLd%2BsTuZWWULFhXbGreGyItdw%2BR9Gsc4A73oRr2vHi0l%2BSQ8oPpH7NdCx4X0JLn8W82k6S%2F4j0Dtz8akNUuVbXaaZg6396K5BW3q7dH8ID%2Fr3PPTLgik0g%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210711T133725Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYZFP56MEU%2F20210711%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7b3cb945bbaec7e62bd4ab47e4ddcdb7c5d39bc1a3f79c168a3cf0f9369ad291&hash=37a2dba19e6a243b3bc7df9fee65282acbbeb87293841407deed49ad1ad0bbf7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0001870807003076&tid=spdf-791c0c2e-cbf4-4de1-85f8-cb680a7b9e29&sid=bbd7a41b73a2514507680db2d7ed01d5c5c1gxrqa&type=client)

Comment: It should be $\Lambda^\gamma\theta(t,0)$ instead of $\Lambda^\gamma\theta(0,x)$!

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks! I will try it again!

Comment: @LL3.14 Can you give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the Fourier transform
$$
\widehat{u}(y) = \mathcal F(u)(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-2iπ \,x\cdot y} \,u(x)\,\mathrm d x.
$$
One can then define the fractional Laplacian of order $s > -1$  by
$$
\Lambda^{s} u(x) = \mathcal F^{-1}(|2\pi y|^{s}\,\widehat{u}(y)).
$$
(so that in particular $\Lambda^{2} = -\Delta$, $\Lambda^{0} = \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb R}$ and $\Lambda^{1} = \Lambda$). With this definition it is easy to see that (if $a>-1$, $b>-1$ and $a+b>-1$)
$$
\Lambda^{a+b} u(x) = \mathcal F^{-1}(|2\pi y|^{a+b}\,\widehat{u}(y)) = \mathcal F^{-1}(|2\pi y|^{a}\mathcal F\mathcal F^{-1}(|2\pi y|^{b}\,\widehat{u}(y)) = \Lambda^{a}\Lambda^{b} u(x).
$$
However, it is also possible to prove$^{1}$ that for $s\in(0,1)$
$$
\Lambda^{s} u(x) = c_s \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{1+s}}\, \mathrm d y
\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
for some constant $c_s = (2\pi)^s \frac{|\omega_{-s}|}{\omega_{d+s}} > 0$ where $\omega_a = \frac{2\,\pi^{a/2}}{\Gamma(a/2)}$. Therefore, defining $u(x) = \theta(t,x)$, in your case you get
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}u)(x)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}u)(0)}{x^{1+\delta}}\,\mathrm dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{(\Lambda^{\gamma}u)(y)-(\Lambda^{\gamma}u)(0)}{|y|^{1+\delta}}\,\mathrm dy
\\
&= -\frac{1}{2\,c_\delta}\,\Lambda^{\delta}(\Lambda^{\gamma}u)(0)
\\
&= -\frac{1}{2\,c_\delta}\,\Lambda^{\gamma+\delta}u(0)
\\
&= \frac{c_{\delta+\gamma}}{2\,c_\delta}\,\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{u(y)-u(0)}{|y|^{1+\delta}}\,\mathrm dy
\\
&= \frac{c_{\delta+\gamma}}{c_\delta}\,\int_{0}^\infty \frac{u(y)-u(0)}{|y|^{1+\delta}}\,\mathrm dy
\end{align*}
$$
So your equality is almost right, except that there is a constant $\frac{c_{\delta+\gamma}}{c_\delta} = (2\pi)^\gamma \,\frac{\omega_{d+\delta}\,\omega_{-\delta-\gamma}}{\omega_{d+\delta+\gamma}\,\omega_{-\delta}}$ in front of the right-hand side.

$~$

---

$^1$ A way to understand and prove the integral formula for the fractional Laplacian and the constant in it is as follows. One can prove by a simple scaling argument (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742640/fx-1-lvert-x-rvert2-x-in-mathbbr3-for-the-fourier-transform/3742759#3742759)) that
$$
\mathcal F\!\left(\frac{1}{\omega_c\,|x|^{c}}\right) = \frac{1}{\omega_{1-c}\, |x|^{1-c}}
$$
for $c∈ (0,1)$. When $c = -s\in(-1,0)$, then the formula is still quite the same but since $1/|x|^{1+s}$ is not locally integrable, it has to be replaced by the distribution $\mathrm P(1/|x|^{1+s})$ defined by
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm P\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{1+s}}\right)\varphi(x)\,\mathrm d x := \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|^{1+s}}\,\mathrm d x.
$$
hence you get
$$
\mathcal F\!\left(\frac{1}{\omega_{-s}\,|x|^{-s}}\right) = \frac{1}{\omega_{1+s}}\mathrm P\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{1+s}}\right)
$$
which can be written
$$
\mathcal F\!\left(|x|^s\right) = \frac{\omega_{-s}}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\mathrm P\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{1+s}}\right)
$$
Now, since the Fourier transform of a product is the convolution of the Fourier transforms, the fractional Laplacian is
$$
\begin{align*}
\Lambda^{s} u(x) &= \mathcal F^{-1}(|2\pi y|^{s}\,\widehat{u}(y)) = (2\pi)^s \, \mathcal F_y(|y|^s) * u
\\
&= \frac{(2\pi)^s\,\omega_{-s}}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\mathrm P\!\left(\frac{1}{|y|^{1+s}}\right) * u
\\
&= \frac{(2\pi)^s\,\omega_{-s}}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm P\!\left(\frac{1}{|y|^{1+s}}\right) u(x-y)\,\mathrm d y
\\
&= \frac{(2\pi)^s\,\omega_{-s}}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{u(x-y)-u(x-0)}{|y|^{1+s}} \,\mathrm d y
\\
&= \frac{(2\pi)^s\,\omega_{-s}}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{u(z)-u(x)}{|x-z|^{1+s}} \,\mathrm d y
\end{align*}
$$
where the last line just follows from the change of variable $y=x-z$. Since $\omega_{-s} = -|\omega_{-s}|$
$$
\begin{align*}
\Lambda^{s} u(x) &= \frac{(2\pi)^s\,|\omega_{-s}|}{\omega_{1+s}}\,\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{u(x)-u(z)}{|x-z|^{1+s}} \,\mathrm d y
\end{align*}
$$
which is Formula $\eqref{1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and clear answer. I learned a lot from it.