# Physical interpretation of fractional Laplacian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Can someone please help me with a physical interpretation of the fractional Laplacian of the principle value definition as in the Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Laplacian

I want to know-how from a physical application such operator can be constructed. I looked at many references, but did not find a suitable one according to my need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A mathematical point of view:** If you are just looking to understand from a mathematical point of view why this integral expression appears, it can be just seen as a convolution with the analogue of the function $|x|^{-(d+\alpha)}$ in theory of distributions, as I explained in the second part of my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195771/how-to-prove-this-integral-equality-which-contains-the-nonlocal-operator-pa/4195979#4195979).

**A physical insight:** If you are looking at physical cases where the fractional Laplacian naturally appear, then you can think of it as the generalization of the generator of the diffusion equation in cases when the thermal equilibrium distribution has high energy. You can look for instance at [Fractional Diffusion Limit](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00205-010-0354-2) for a rigorous derivation

Let me clarify, summarize, simplify with the following heuristic point of view: if you have a physical system at thermal equilibrium (the distribution of the velocities is reached at each point) and the equilibrium of the velocities are similar to a Gaussian, or more generally no high velocities, then from far away (mathematically, after a change of scaling and taking a limit), in average, it seems like the velocities are random and so you get the heat equation:
$$
\partial_t\rho(t,x) = \Delta\rho(t,x)
$$
i.e. the time variation of your density of particles $\rho(x)$ is proportional to a local variation of itself.

When some velocities are really high (thermal equilibrium with heavy tails), then from far away and at a macroscopic time scale, the particles with very high velocities are almost teleporting. Hence the time variation of your density of particles $\rho(x)$ is not local anymore, since you have to take into account the particles that left the point $x$ and were from a macroscopic point of view "teleported" to a point $y$. So the more general equation is of the form
$$
\partial_t \rho(x) = \int (\rho(y)-\rho(x))\, g(x-y)\, \mathrm d y
$$
where roughly speaking, $g(x-y)$ represents the number of particles that will go from $x$ to $y$. In the case when $g(x) = |x|^{-(d+\alpha)}$ is homogeneous, you get a fractional Laplacian.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these intuitions! Is it correct to think of taking $\alpha \to 0^+$ as increasing the proportion of high-velocity particles? The smaller the value of $\alpha$, the more "delocalized" the generalized diffusion process becomes?

Comment: I ask because having an interpretation for the small fractional powers could help one get intuition for the zeta function/functional determinant of the Laplacian.