# Fourier transform of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^n}$ and $f(t)=\frac{1}{\left(1+|x|\right)^n}$ where $n>0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I was looking for the FT of the symmetric functions:

1. $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^n}$ and/or
2. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1+|x|\right)^n}$

where $n>0$. Here $-\infty \leq x \leq \infty$. I expect the FT to be symmetric and exponentially deceasing. Could you please guide me to the answer or provide a proof?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that the FT is only exponentially decaying if $n$ is an even integer.

Comment: i guess your t should be x. And Fabian should be right; smoothness of $f$ corresponds to decay of the FT. But symmetric they will be (this should not be hard to prove)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as in my asnwer to the other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431042/fourier-transform-of-t-n?noredirect=1&lq=1), these functions can be bounded above by $C/|x|$ and do not have an exponential decay (except if $n$ is an even integer and $f$ is of the form 1.). Perhaps what you did not remark is just the fact that $(1+|x|^2)^{-n}$ is infinitely smooth, while $(1+|x|)^{-n}$ is as smooth as $|x|$ at $x=0$, and this is what prevents the exponential decay of their Fourier transform.

I do not know any simple expression for their Fourier transform in general, however, one can still obtain the decay of their Fourier transform by comparing to a function with a similar local behavior. For example, if $n=1$, then $f(x) = (1+|x|)^{-1}$ has the same behavior as $g(x) = e^{-|x|}$. More precisely,
$$
h(x) = f(x) - g(x)
$$
has its (weak) third derivative in $L^\infty$ and so $|h(x)| \leq C/|x|^3$ for large $x$. Now, the explicit Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ is (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4220006/computing-the-fourier-transform-of-exponential-decay-in-mathbbr2))
$$
\widehat{g}(y) = \frac{2}{1+|y|^2}
$$
and so one deduces that
$$
\mathcal F((1+|x|)^{-1}) = \frac{2}{|x|^2} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right)
$$
when $|x|\to\infty$.

The same is true for any $n>0$, $\mathcal F((1+|x|)^{-n}) \sim \frac{C}{|x|^2}$ when $|x|\to\infty$.