# Integral involving Fourier transform of 1/|X|

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In the context of reproducing some known expressions, I'm trying to simplify the integral
$$
\int \dfrac{dx dy}{|x-y|} \delta(x-r_j)\delta(y-r_l) \;,
$$
which I know it should give as result
$$
\int \dfrac{dk}{k^2}e^{-i k r_j}e^{-i k r_l} \;.
$$
[Here I reported the integrals I actually care about in a simplified form, so that the main point of the calculation is emphasised. More actual details are not so relevant.]

I think that the idea in going from the first to the second integral must involve the Fourier transform, but I was not able to find out how. I have the impression one has to FT the fraction, and then integrate out $x,y$, but by taking FT of $1/|x|$ I get stuck.

Comment: Using the Fourier transform, we have
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{dx dy}{|x-y|} \delta(x-r_j)\delta(x-r_l) &= \int dx \delta(x-r_j) \int dy \frac{e^{-i k (y-r_l)}}{|y-x|} \
&= \int dx \delta(x-r_j) \int dk \frac{e^{-i k (r_l-r_j)}}{k^2} \
&= \int \frac{dk}{k^2} e^{-i k (r_l-r_j)} \int dx \delta(x-r_j) \
&= \int \frac{dk}{k^2} e^{-i k (r_l-r_j)} \
&= \int \frac{dk}{k^2} e^{-i k r_j} e^{-i k r_l}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of the Dirac delta, your integral is just
$$
I = \int \frac{1}{|r_j-y|} \,\delta(y-r_l) \,\mathrm d y = \frac{1}{|r_j-r_l|}
$$
Assuming that you works in dimension $3$, the Fourier transform of $1/|x|$ is $1/(2\pi^2|x|^2)$, so the above function is just the Fourier transform of $1/(2\pi^2|x|^2)$ evaluated at $r_j-r_l$, that is
$$
I = \int e^{-i(r_j-r_l)k} \frac{1}{2\pi^2|k|^2} \,\mathrm d k.
$$
In particular, you have a sign error in one of the exponentials.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just confused by one thing: How is the FT of $1/|x|$ giving $1/(2\pi^2|x|^2)$, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Yrs, this is a well-known result that you can get just by scaling, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742640/fx-1-lvert-x-rvert2-x-in-mathbbr3-for-the-fourier-transform